# Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2:jar is missing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

Problem:

I am following a tutorial on creating a Spring Boot oAuth2 Server https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhY8q5B0s-s&list=PLD-mYtebG3X-wOVHINZf_GKknpJs3Oa3O&index=9. It says to update the pom.xml file as follows which is when I get the following build error.

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>imort</scope>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

```
[ERROR]   The project com.example.auth:auth-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (D:\krish-fullstack-training\MicroservicesDemo\auth-server\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2:jar is missing. @ line 28, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security:jar is missing. @ line 32, column 15
```

I tried changing the pom file dependencies accordingly, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-oauth2/2.2.5.RELEASE,https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-security/2.2.5.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The build still doesn't work after a maven clean. What can I do to fix this? Thanks.

Solution:

I had to change my dependencies to these and it worked. (Just in case anyone came across the same problem). However, I am not yet sure why the above dependencies didn't work.

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Does it still throwing the same error after the recent change you made?